# How to close Callkit screen after VOIP call disconnected

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip, callkit, pushkit

I am trying to remove callkit screen once my voip call is disconnected by source or destination.

I used this code

```
CXEndCallAction *endaction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:[NSUUID UUID]];
CXCallController *callController = [[CXCallController alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
requestTransaction:[CXTransaction transactionWithActions:nil completion:completion]];
```

But it is not working to close the callkit. Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this below method on call disconnected method.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CXCallController *callKitCallController;

- (void)performEndCallActionWithUUID:(NSUUID *)uuid {
    if (uuid == nil) {
        return;
    }

    CXEndCallAction *endCallAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:uuid];
    CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:endCallAction];

    [self.callKitCallController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"EndCallAction transaction request failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"EndCallAction transaction request successful");
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your `CXTransaction` with `CXEndCallAction` into your `requestTransaction`.

First of all in `initWithCallUUID` you have to pass your current call `NSUUID`. Then you can call `requestTransaction` on your `CXCallController` and pass `[CXTransaction transactionWithActions:@[endaction]` into it, instead of `nil` as you did.

```
CXEndCallAction *endaction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:[NSUUID UUID]]; // your current call UUID
CXCallController *callController = [[CXCallController alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[callController requestTransaction:[CXTransaction transactionWithActions:@[endaction]] completion:completion];
```