# How to Remove top bar in the IOS CallKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

I am using `callkit` and `Pushkit` in my App. after using callkit when my app going in background a red view show in top of the screen even i have disconnected the call.

How to Remove this top View programmatically.

here is screenshot of issue. [image]

i am disconnecting phone call. using this link

[CallKit Call Dissconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45341414/4970453)

Comment: This is an iOS limitation. I think it's a privacy thing. Apple wants the users to know that they're in a phone call wherever they are. Same for apps who are monitoring location in the background, or recording audio.

Comment: This is not an issue. This default behavior of iOS.

Comment: @ TawaNicolas .. when i am not in any phone call ..  this top view is showing evry time when minimize the App.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `CallKit` framework, that bar should be green. Red is often used to indicate a SIP call without `CallKit` framework implementation. But if you say that call is ended and bar is still there, that means you haven't ended a call properly using `CallKit`. Which means it still indicates an active SIP call.

You can get `UUID` of a call when you `reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID` and when you reporting outgoing call with `[[CXStartCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID`. In that method you create and pass your `UUID`.

```
NSUUID *callUUID = [NSUUID UUID];
```

You have to keep track of it!

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue. It's default behavior of iOS.

You can see the similar behavior when you are in a Phone call, monitoring location in the background, recording audio, Video call(eg: Skype).

Comment: when i disconnect Phone call.. red top bar not gone after disconnecting call.

Answer (score 0):

Your audio session still a recoding Session (like play and record audio session) that's why the red bar still on top. That indicate to the user that your app is recording audio like it was mentioned in previous comments (normal iOS behaviour). If you want to remove the red bar after a call is ended, switch you audio session to a non recoding one like the ambient audio session.

Answer (score 0):

Red banner means `AVAudioSession` is still active. Use CallKit's provider method to deactivate your audio engine

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession)
```